# Is it possible to insert multiple values using insert in sql

Tags: sql, db2

Is it possible to insert in one single query multiple values into a table ? .

I have declared this table

```sql
declare global temporary table CFVariables
    (
        CF varchar(255)
    )
with replace ;
```

then i inserted values into the table

```sql
INSERT INTO qtemp.CFVariables ( CF ) VALUES
('F01' ), ('T01' ), ('U01' ), ('CIP' ), ('L01' )
```

Is it possible to not insert  the values in qtemp.CFVariables table this way ?  but like **In** ('F01' , 'T01' , 'U01' , 'CIP' , 'L01' )

Then , i declared my second table :

```sql
declare global temporary table xVariables
    (
        CFC  numeric(3),
        CF varchar(255)
    )
with replace ;
```

In this part i'm having a problem to insert into my table **xVariables**

I tried to use this to insert multiple values

```sql
INSERT INTO qtemp.xVariables ( CFC, CF ) VALUES
( 1, (select CF from  qtemp.CFVariables ))
```

My query field because i'm inserting more then one row to the table .
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: I'm using IBM Db2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running an insert-select:

```
INSERT INTO qtemp.xVariables ( CFC, CF )
select 1, CF from  qtemp.CFVariables
```

To restrict the records to be inserted, you will need to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO qtemp.xVariables ( CFC, CF )
select 1, CF 
from  qtemp.CFVariables 
where CF in ('F01' , 'T01' , 'U01' , 'CIP' , 'L01' )
```

Comment: Is it possible to not insert  the values in qtemp.CFVariables table this way ?  but like in ('F01' , 'T01' , 'U01' , 'CIP' , 'L01' )

Comment: @Kakoo16 please elaborate. From what you ask, to me it seems that the way this answer is inserting is good, but you want to restrict the set of records to be inserted to the listed items. Am I understanding you accurately?

Comment: Yes ! it's correct I want to restrict the set of records to be inserted to the listed items

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
INSERT INTO qtemp.xVariables ( CFC, CF ) SELECT 1 AS CFC,CF from  qtemp.CFVariables;
```

Comment: Is it possible to not insert  the values in qtemp.CFVariables table this way ?  but like in ('F01' , 'T01' , 'U01' , 'CIP' , 'L01' )

Comment: After VALUES clause ?

Comment: INSERT INTO qtemp.CFVariables ( CF ) VALUES WHERE CF IN (
('F01' , 'T01' , 'U01' ,'CIP' , 'L01' )

Comment: Have you look our answer, there is no VALUES clause ... just add the WHERE clause at the end of the query given in the answer.

Comment: I have updated my question  im trying to change the insert part of qtemp.CFVariables  table to be more like a list IN ( ('F01' , 'T01' , 'U01' ,'CIP' , 'L01' )

Comment: Difficult to follow and not fair to change the question. Please close this post (best answer for one answer, upvote for the other one since both other are the same at the same time) and open a new one.